# Finding the rectangle surrounding a capsule defined by two points while minimizing trig, and square root

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

For the visuals of a simulation I need to solve the following problem.
[image]

I know points one and two (shown in yellow) and the length of the green line. I need to find the four purple points surrounding the capsule this creates. This capsule is basically constructed as a rectangle between the two points with the width of a green line. Then a semicircle is added to each end with a radius matching the width of the rectangle (green line).

This would be an easy task just using polar coordinates however two issues come to mind.

1. Each drawing has direction, somehow c1 and c2 need to be on the same side as p1, and c3 and c4 need to be on the same side as p2. Because sometimes p1 will be to the left or below p2 this poses problems.
2. This calculation has to be preformed by an old cpu thousands of times many times a second. If at all possible a minimum amount of trigonometric and square root operations preformed.

So far I have been able to find the location of the 4 corners of the inner rectangle (black) by normalizing the vector between the two points, multiplying by the width. Then I use that value and add or subtract it from p1 in order to find those corners.

Theoretically this same method could be used if I could find the location of the point that bisects the line made by c1 and c2 (and c3 and c4). However I would have to use 2 cosines, and 2 sines in order to figure that out. And I would likely have issues with order of points.

Is there a faster way that also keeps p1, c1, and c2 on the same side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Let your position vector be $\vec{P_1}=[x_1,y_1]$ and your direction vector between $P_1$ and $P_2$ be normalized $\vec{u}= \dfrac{[x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1]}{d}$ where $d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$.

Let $\vec{n}=\dfrac{[y_2-y_1,x_1-x_2,]}{d}$ be a normal vector to segment $P_1P_2$. Then $\vec{c_3}$ and $\vec{c_4}$ are the two vectors $\vec{P_1}+(d+r)\vec{u}\pm r\vec{n}$ and the vectors $\vec{c_1}$ and $\vec{c_2}$ are $\vec{P_1}-r\vec{u}\pm r\vec{n}$.

Given the labeling of your diagram I believe the equations would be as follows:

\begin{equation}
\vec{c_1}=\vec{P_1}-r(\vec{u}-\vec{n})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vec{c_2}=\vec{P_1}-r(\vec{u}+\vec{n})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vec{c_3}=\vec{P_1}+(d+r)\vec{u}-r\vec{n}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vec{c_4}=\vec{P_1}+(d+r)\vec{u}+r\vec{n}
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that $\vec{n}$ is formed by switching the two coordinates of $\vec{u}$ and then changing the sign of the second component.

Comment: Note that if you know the coordinates of $P_1$ and $P_2$ and the length of the green line, then no trigonometry is required to find the coordinates of $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4.$

Comment: When you call each of the corners of a vector you mean a vector from what point? What should I add the vector to to get my desired point?

Comment: When you say that you "know" $P_1$ and $P_2$ I assume that you mean you know their coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. Think of those coordinates as the horizontal and vertical components of vectors. The coordinates of $c_1,\cdots,c_4$ are likewise the horizontal and vertical components of vectors. $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{n}$ computed as indicated above are unit vectors (they have length $=1$) perpendicular to each other. $u$ is in the direction $P_1P_2$ and $\vec{n}$ is perpendicular to that. $r$ is the radius of the end cap and equals half the width of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$p_i = (x_i, y_i), \quad i \in \{1, 2\}$$ and let $w$ be the capsule width.  The desired points of the bounding rectangle are given by $$\begin{align*} 
\left( x_1 + \frac{w}{2d} (x_1 - x_2 - y_1 + y_2), y_1 + \frac{w}{2d} (x_1 - x_2 + y_1 - y_2) \right), \\
\left( x_1 + \frac{w}{2d} (x_1 - x_2 + y_1 - y_2), y_1 + \frac{w}{2d} (-x_1 + x_2 + y_1 - y_2) \right), \\
\left( x_2 + \frac{w}{2d} (-x_1 + x_2 - y_1 + y_2), y_2 + \frac{w}{2d} (x_1 - x_2 - y_1 + y_2) \right), \\ 
\left( x_2 + \frac{w}{2d} (-x_1 + x_2 + y_1 - y_2), y_2 + \frac{w}{2d} (-x_1 + x_2 - y_1 + y_2) \right),
\end{align*}$$ where $d = |p_1 - p_2| = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2}$ is the distance between $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: This formula causes all the points to be defined when the two points are too close to each other. I have tried forcing the distance to be greater then 0 and then moving the x and y coordinate by an offset but oddly enough that ends up generating a shape of completely different size.

Comment: @J.Doe  I am not sure what you mean.  From a programming perspective, $d/w$ would have to be on the order of $10^{-16}$ to have issues with floating point arithmetic.  What are some example values of $p_1, p_2, w$ that you are considering?

Comment: I digress. My observation was that things like p1:(200,200) p2:(200.1, 200.1) created only a small dot, however that was just me changing distance to be greater then 1. I must now find a solution for when the particle is not moving.

Answer (score 0):

Can your restrict the angles to specific values?  For example, is one degree accuracy on the angle good enough or can you force the angle to be a multiple of one degree?  Then you can make a table of sines at startup and use the fact that $\cos \theta^\circ = \sin (90-\theta)^\circ$.  Then you don't need any square roots, either, because you have both $\sin$ and $\cos$.  A table of $9,000$ entries can give you $0.01^\circ$ resolution.

Comment: Did you mean to post this answer to a different question?  It doesn't seem related to this particular question.

Comment: No I can not, I have messed with that but in the long run it is better to not

Comment: @heropup: no this is the right question.  I did what I recommend many years ago because processors did not have numeric coprocessors available.  I was able to restrict my angles to multiples of $5^\circ$ and only use an $18$ item table.  Combined with making all the distances ints instead of floats because I knew the scale there was a huge speedup.  All my operations were integer until the sin/cos came in, then I converted back to int to add up a lot of terms.  This was in the day when 640k was the maximum memory available.

Comment: @RossMillikan That is absolutely insane. Props to you programmers who managed to do so much back when 640k was the maximum memory! Wowzers!